# Testing RequireJS with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, requirejs, jasmine

I'm very new to Javascript and I'm trying to write tests for a project I've joined in on. I have files in the program that look like this:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'backbone/models/beat',
  'colors',
  'app/dispatch',
  'app/log'
], function($, _, Backbone, BeatModel, COLORS, dispatch, log){
  return Backbone.View.extend({

    getOpacityNumber : function(bool) {
      //code
    },

    unroll: function(){
      //code
    }
  });
});
```

And I can't figure out how to access these functions in a test. I've tried instantiating an object (although I may be doing it wrong) and calling the functions from there like this:

```
describe("beatView.js", function() {
    beforeEach( function() {
            var b = new beatView();
    });

    spyOn(console, "log");

    it("test the console log", function() {
        b.unroll();
        expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

But when I run it I get a reference error that Jasmine cannot find the variable b. Is there something that I'm missing? Any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
describe("beatView.js", function() {
    var b = null;
    beforeEach( function() {
            b = new beatView();
    });

    spyOn(console, "log");

    it("test the console log", function() {
        b.unroll();
        expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay so now it can find the variable b but the issue is that now I get `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: beatView` I don't know how to reference the object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Jasmine wery well, but can't you just `describe()` the test inside of a `require()` call?

```
require(["beatView"], function (beatView) {
  describe(...);
});
```